# MongoDB : how to find max sequenced documents in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the below MongoDB documents in a collection called 'Student'.
This document contains details about Student and the revision information. I basically wanted to get the maximum sequence out of it based on some filter condition.

```
{
    
    "student": {
        name : "Rahul",
        age  : 18,
        department : "CSE",
        section : "B"
    },
    
    "sequence": 0,
    "student_ref": "AUTCSE024",
    "college" : "AUT"
}

{
    
    "student": {
        name : "Rahul",
        age  : 18,
        department : "CSE",
        section : "A"
    },
    
    "sequence": 1,
    "student_ref": "AUTCSE024",
    "college" : "AUT"
}

{
    
    "student": {
        name : "Kumar",
        age  : 18,
        department : "IT",
        section : "A"
    },
    
    "sequence": 0,
    "student_ref": "AUTITE011",
    "college" : "AUT"
}

{
    
    "student": {
        name : "Kumar",
        age  : 18,
        department : "IT",
        section : "C"
    },
    
    "sequence": 1,
    "student_ref": "AUTITE011",
    "college" : "AUT"
}

{
    
    "student": {
        name : "Praveen",
        age  : 18,
        department : "IT",
        section : "C"
    },
    
    "sequence": 0,
    "student_ref": "AUTITE016",
    "college" : "AUT"
}

{
    
    "student": {
        name : "Praveen",
        age  : 18,
        department : "IT",
        section : "C"
    },
    
    "sequence": 1,
    "student_ref": "AUTITE016",
    "college" : "AUT"
}
```

So from the above documents, I wanted the output based on max(sequence) and "student.department" : "IT". The expected result should be

```
{
    
    "student": {
        name : "Kumar",
        age  : 18,
        department : "IT",
        section : "C"
    },
    
    "sequence": 1,
    "student_ref": "AUTITE011",
    "college" : "AUT"
}
{
    
    "student": {
        name : "Praveen",
        age  : 18,
        department : "IT",
        section : "C"
    },
    
    "sequence": 1,
    "student_ref": "AUTITE016",
    "college" : "AUT"
}
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: What is the definition of "maximum"? Is there some grouping condition then you want to take max sequence inside each groups?

Comment: For a given  "student_ref" value, it can return more than 1 document. So, out of that need to fetch only one document whose "sequence" has max number or value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sub-pipeline in `$lookup` to aggregate the max sequence number. Then filter the student results by matching the `sequence` field with the aggregated max sequence number.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Y1R3HoBbiS) for your reference.